# How to specify backups destination folder in TimeMachine

Tags: time-machine, backup

In TimeMachine settings I can choose only device where to store backups. But I don't want to see backups in the root directory of my external hdd.
I have directories like:
 - Backups
 - Movies
 - Music
 - Photos

And I want to force TimeMachine store backups in /Backups directory, not in the root of hdd.

Comment: Why not have two folders at the root? Backups and other. Then just look at Other when you want to see what you wanted in root?

Comment: I don't think what you are asking can be implemented!!!